# How to debug NativeScript mobile app using Telerik AppBuilder

Tags: android, ios, telerik, hybrid-mobile-app, nativescript

I am using Telerik AppBuilder trial version(3.5.1) for the mobile app using NativeScript. I am getting only "Build" and "Build and Deploy" options. But I am unable to debug our app.

I am beginner in NativeScript, even I don't know, how to put break point for debug. Please help. I will be highly obliged.

Comment: you will find description in the documentation - http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/nativescript/debugging-your-code/debug-app , how to debug your NativeScript code

Comment: I have tried to debug as per documentation.  But unable to put break point and not getting any command to run in debug mode.